# Google Spreadsheet Api. Limit per user per 100 sec not reached but getting ratelimited

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

Im trying to work with the google spreadsheet api (V4) which states to have the following limitation.

*This version of the Google Sheets API has a limit of 500 requests per 100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user. Limits for reads and writes are tracked separately. There is no daily usage limit.*

Somehow my code gets ratelimited after 21-34 requestes.
I am able to see the send requests to the api in the google api dashboard which shows the same numbers on a 1 to 1 match. Thus, i am sending less than 100 requests and i am still getting rate limited.

The Endpoint which is failing is the v4/spreadsheets/{id} ep. Maybe this has an influence on it as i read that there f.e. was a not documented rate limitation for the creation of calenders via the calender api.

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: I think that providing your current script might help users think of the issue and solution. How about this?

Comment: It is just a for loop opening files. The called functions only perform one api call i checked that, dashboard also proofs that.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I could correctly image your whole script and find your issue from the images script, I would like to think of the solution. So when you give me a time to do, I'm glad.

Comment: So your code is basically a for loop making [GET](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) requests for several Spreadsheets? Are these inside the same folder? This information could be helpful for trying to reproduce your issue. Could you add a small delay inside the loop to wait a second or so between requests to troubleshoot what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Yes each file is requested by a get request. All files are in the same folder. I already tryd adding 1-3 sek delay between each request with the same result.

Comment: Thanks for that information. Could you please add a sample piece of code *(with no sensitive data)* so that I can try to reproduce your issue as accurately as possible? Thanks again ! :D